# Sencha-touch 1.1: Getting Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: database, json, sencha-touch, undefined

Hi I'm trying to read my json data but it keep showing the loading screen. I'm trying to load my data in a list with pictures and some info. It works with inline data. But when I try to use JSON it doesnt work.

Can someone point me out what I did wrong or forgot? I have never worked with JSON before.

My .json file:

```
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "Shirt",
                "sizes": "S/M/L",
                "price": "19,95",
                "thumb": "shirt.jpeg"
            },
            {
                "name": "Vest",
                "sizes": "S/M/L",
                "price": "24,95",
                "thumb": "vest.jpeg"
            },
            {
                "name": "Knitted vest",
                "sizes": "S/M/L",
                "price": "29,95",
                "thumb": "knittedvest.jpeg"
            },
            {
                "name": "T-Shirt",
                "sizes": "S/M/L",
                "price": "9,95",
                "thumb": "tshirt.jpeg"
            },
            {
                "name": "Jacket",
                "sizes": "S/M/L",
                "price": "69,95",
                "thumb": "jacket.jpeg"
            },
            {
                "name": "Trui",
                "sizes": "S/M/L",
                "price": "29,95",
                "thumb": "trui.jpeg"
            },
            {
                "name": "Overhemd",
                "sizes": "S/M/L",
                "price": "29,95",
                "thumb": "overhemd.jpeg"
            },
            {
                "name": "Grandad",
                "sizes": "S/M/L",
                "price": "19,95",
                "thumb": "grandad.jpeg"
            }
        ]
    }
```

My model.js:

```
    Ext.regModel('Tops', {                          
        fields: [
            {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'sizes', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'price', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'thumb', type: 'string'},
            ]
    });
```

my store.js:

```
    App.views.topwearstores = new Ext.data.Store({              
        model: 'Tops',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/data/topwear_data.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data'
            },  
        },
    });
```

my view.js:

```
    App.views.WishlistIndex = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {

            layout: 'fit',   
            items: {
                xtype: 'list',
                itemTpl:
                    '<tpl for".">'+
                    '<div id="Catalog_Itemimage"><img class="Catalog_Image" src="res/images/kleding/dude/{thumb}" height="75px" width="75px"/></div>'+ 
                    '<div id="Catalog_info">'+
                    '<div id="Catalog_name">{name}</div>'+
                    '<div id="Catalog_price">&#8364;{price}</div>'+
                    '<div id="Catalog_sizes">Sizes: {sizes}</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</tpl>',               
                store: App.views.topwearstores,

                singleSelect: true,
                itemSelector: 'div.Catalog_Info',
            },

    });
    Ext.reg('WishlistIndex', App.views.WishlistIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm new at this too, and I've had the length of undefined error a few times.

Your code seems fine to me, but one thing that caused this in my project was that the references to the various files were in the **wrong order** in the index.html.